# How do I level a pipe with the ground?

Tags: pipe

I have a drain made of PVC pipe on my back porch.  The PVC pipe sticks up from the concrete about an inch or so.  What is the best way to cut the pipe down so that it will be level with the concrete?  What tools do I need?

Comment: why do you wish to cut back the pipe, it will be very hard to fix to once it has been cut back.

Comment: It's a tripping hazard.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: I'm not home now, but imagine it's like this: http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/4496/4496,1218049324,2/stock-photo-two-iron-pipes-sticking-out-of-the-ground-on-side-of-road-15824698.jpg, but it's a pvc pipe about 6" in diameter and sticking out of the ground about 1".

Comment: Is there a cap on it?  It could be a clean out, in which case if you do cut it down you'll still need to be able to put the cap on it.

Comment: @Tester101 - there is a grate inside the pipe, but no actual cap.  The grate sits flush with the top of the pipe.

Comment: Will the grate fit after cutting the pipe level with the ground?

Comment: @Tester101 - it should, provided the diameter doesn't change, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Around here, drain pipes are usually 4" diameter. Sewer pipe is likely to be plugged, as there's nasty stuff in there (duh). Since it doesn't have a cap, I would guess it's a gutter drain.

Comment: @Jay - good point, I'm pretty sure it's a gutter drain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those [oscillating](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=oscillating+multi+tool&hl=en&prmd=ivns&resnum=3&biw=1280&bih=847&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=17208579913424948060&ei=is4tTcX7M8GB8gaYh4mfCQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CGUQ8wIwAg) tools would be perfect for this.

[image]

But before cutting it you might want to figure out what it's for, and if you'll need it in the future.  Cutting the pipe should be fairly easy; but if you ever have to, making it longer is more difficult.

Comment: These things are awesome.

Comment: The original is the Fein MultiMaster, which sells for $300-$400. I used one when the schooner Adventuress was getting new bunks in the fo'c'sl, and it was a very sweet tool. For anyone who will use it often, it's great! According to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fein_Multimaster) the patent expired in 2008, and now there are many clones. Even Harbor Freight has them for $35 (http://www.harborfreight.com/multifunction-power-tool-67256.html) but it will probably turn to trash quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Take a 12" hacksaw **blade** out of the hacksaw itself, press it flat against the floor and start sawing.

The blade should be flexible enough for this and will cut as close to the floor as possible.

You will want to hold the end of the saw blade with a cloth or gloves to avoid cutting your hand.

Comment: Or wrap some duct tape around one end of the hacksaw blade to create a handle.

Comment: @Tester101 - that would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

As tester101 suggests, the best power tool way is probably an oscillating tool.

For a cheaper (hand tool) solution, a jamb saw is primarily designed for cutting the bottom of door jambs to install flooring, but in general is for cutting flat against a surface.

[image]

Comment: Will work, but working close to concrete surface will abrase and damage the saw blade so one has to decide if he can tolerate that.

Answer (score 0):

If you cut it flush, it will be very difficult to extend later, if the need ever arises. An alternative is to protect against tripping by putting a table or an orange cone ([$15 from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00113HWH4)) over it.